# How to install Github on USB Drive?

Tags: git, github, usb, portable-applications

Is it possible to Github and Powershell on a USB drive. And I need it to work just like it would on my computer. Like open the shell through the Github and open the shell from selecting a repository.

Comment: You can't install Github anywhere.

Comment: @JorgeGajon: He probably means GitHub for Windows.

Comment: Ah, didn't know there was such a thing. My apologies.

Comment: He probably just means git!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Portable GIT client for windows, here is it's beta version:
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.8.0-preview20121022.7z&can=2&q=

Just extract it in your USB drive, now you can use git on any pc without install

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
you can use **cameyo** to make almost any app portable. http://www.cameyo.com/